# Document Icon not displaying under SP Document Associated Grid within Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Has anyone else ran into the issue where the document icon won't load under the 'SP Document Associated Grid' default view under the related Documents section on a main entity such as Account or Opportunity?

It does load when changing the drop down to 'All Sharepoint Documents' view though.  I need it to load within the 'SP Associated Grid' because you cannot change this default view under Settings.  Any insight on getting those icons to show?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I'm afraid this question looks off topic to me. Can you add some code? How is this question related to programming?

Comment: No code for this, just a question to see if anyone else has experienced this out of the box setting for D365 integration with SP online.  I added the appropriate tags

Comment: Inspect in browser for this element, check the URL or CSS. May be caching problem. Cross browser behavior?